# How to concatenate strings in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile that runs pandoc. I want to turn a list of extensions:

```
PANDOC_EXTENSIONS = \
        multiline_tables \
        some_other_extension
```

into a string that looks like:

```
PANDOC_EXTENSION_LIST = +multiline_tables+some_other_extension
```

which will then be passed as a command line option to pandoc like this:

```
pandoc --from$(PANDOC_EXTENSION_LIST) ...
```

It's trivial in almost any programming language, but I can't figure out how to do this with the patsubst or subst functions, since make doesn't really have lists. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

**Makefile**

```
PANDOC_EXTENSIONS = \
        multiline_tables \
        some_other_extension


$(foreach word,$(PANDOC_EXTENSIONS),$(eval PANDOC_EXTENSION_LIST := $(PANDOC_EXTENSION_LIST)+$(word)))

.PHONY: all

all:
    echo $(PANDOC_EXTENSION_LIST)
```

Which runs like:

```
$ make
echo +multiline_tables+some_other_extension
+multiline_tables+some_other_extension
```

As this illustrates, GNU make really does have lists. A sequence of whitespace-separated words is a list.

Answer (score 1):

Based on example in [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Syntax-of-Functions):

```
empty:=
space:=$(empty) $(empty)
PANDOC_EXTENSIONS = \
        multiline_tables \
        some_other_extension

all:
    @echo +$(subst ${space},+,${PANDOC_EXTENSIONS})
```

The result:

```
$ gmake                                                                                                    
+multiline_tables+some_other_extension
```